# RequireJS Config mapping whole directories

Tags: javascript, web, requirejs, amd

Is it possible to map a whole directory the `node_modules` directory for example to `src/lib/` in the require config?

**Sample Project:**

```
project/  
project/node_modules  
project/src/  
project/src/lib/
```

Comment: By map do you mean configure the `path`?

Comment: @Shuhel With RequireJS terminology I want the the functional equivalent of using config.path on all of the files in the directories specified while be implicitly defined in the config file using their parent directories instead of doing it for each and every one. For example I want to call require['../node_node_module/jquery'] as require['lib/jquery'].

Comment: Still not sure what you want but in RequireJS you actually can configure `paths` that points to a folder. And, you can name your path whatever you want. For example, if you have a folder named `node_modules` and you have some libs there including jquery, you can configure a path like, 
`require.config({paths: {'lib' : '/path_to_node_module_folder' }});` and later in your module you can require jquery like `define(['lib/jquery', function($){ .... }])`. Does it answer your question?

Comment: Make that an answer and I will accept it. For some reason, it didn't click with me to configure the path of directories and not just individual JavaScript assets.

Comment: I did make it an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In RequireJS you actually can configure `paths` that points to a folder. And, you can name your path whatever you want. For example, if you have a folder named `node_modules` and you have some libs in there including jquery, you can configure a path like

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'lib' : '/path_to_node_module_folder' 
  }
});
```

and later in your module you can require jquery like

```
define(['lib/jquery'], function($){ 
     .... 
});
```